# I have created a subdirectory in my codeigniter Application But its Showing 404

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have application in the application in my domain. Domain.com is working fine with CodeIgniter 2.26 release and now I am updating it on new version 3.x and its working fine on localhost. I uploaded the new version on C-panel domain.com/newversion and my default controller and all routes are perfect but still showing 404 not found.

Comment: did you start  filename and class name with capital letter as it will not work if you used small letter

Comment: Are you sure that you set base_url in your config correctly?